# Is using interface as model for views in ASP.NET MVC a bad practice

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I guess the title pretty much sums up what I'm trying to ask.

Here's a lame example what I'm trying to do

```
public interface IMyObject
{
    string Property1 {get;set;}
    List<string> PropertyList {get;set;}
    string GetOneValue();

}

public class MyObject
{
    public string Property1 {get;set;}
    public List<string> PropertyList {get;set;}

    public string GetOneValue()
    {
        return PropertyList.Find(p=>p.Name=="MyName");
    }
}


public class MyFactory
{
    public IMyObject GetMeMyObject()
    {
        // perform some db query and return interface.. like
        IMyObject obj = null;
        using(context = new dbcontext())
         obj = context.MyObjects.Where(o=>o.Value == "somevalue").FirstOrDefault<IMyObject>();

        return obj;
    }
}


public class MyController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        IMyObject objInterface = new MyFactory().GetMeMyObject();
        return View(objInterface);
    }   
}


Index.cshtml

@model MyLib.IMyObject

<h1>@Model.Property1</h1>
<p>@Model.GetOneValue()</p>
```

Here I am using interface as a model to the cshtml view. 
My questions are,

1. Is this a bad practice ?
2. Is there disadvantages to what I am doing here ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is always a good idea to do code for abstraction in OOPS as it's making your code as loosely coupled. I believe it's a good way to do code in MVC

Answer (score 2):

My two cents would be that I would only add it if it adds some sort of value to what you are trying to achieve. In most cases a model object will be a simple POCO, so you have to consider if abstraction is needed.

I guess a potential benefit could be more flexible views since you have a dependency on the interface and not a concrete object. Meaning you could reuse the view for different implementers of the interface. Again, I would only do it when it adds value though.

Answer (score 1):

Let me turn the question "Is there a disadvantage?" around: Is there an *advantage*? I don't see one, at least not for your example.

Will you ever be providing an alternate implementation of your model to your view? If not, don't use an interface. In general, models should be pretty lightweight, mostly consisting of properties and maybe a tiny amount of logic for mutating internal state.

The interface should represent a contract for your object: "Here's a bunch of stuff that I guarantee this thing will be able to do." If you don't need to make that guarantee because there's only one object that can reasonably do those things, don't use an interface.